# I am using physics.checkbox to instantiate objects and it is not working the right way

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, instantiation, spawn

I am trying to instantiate a wall in front of a player when a button is clicked. I am using physics.checkbox for this because I want to check if there is any wall or gameObject already in front of my player. According to code, "Position not available" always gets printed in console ignoring the fact if there is any collider at the spawning position or not. I don't know if I am using it right or not. Help.

```
public class WallBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject horizontal, vertical;

    public void BuildWallButton()
    {
        Vector3 verticalWallPosition = new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x, this.gameObject.transform.position.y + 3, this.transform.position.z+0.05f);

        if (Physics.CheckBox(verticalWallPosition, vertical.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.extents,Quaternion.identity))
        {
            Debug.Log("Available");
            GameObject upWays = Instantiate(vertical, verticalWallPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(verticalWallPosition.y);
            Debug.Log("Position not available");
        }
        //GameObject sideWays = Instantiate(horizontal, horizontalWallPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking 3 units above the player? And are you sure the Colliders extends are big enough?

Comment: You know btw that you can reduce that line `Vector3 verticalWallPosition = new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x, this.gameObject.transform.position.y + 3, this.transform.position.z+0.05f);` to `Vector3 verticalWallPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 3, 0.05f);` .. do you maybe want to check in front of the player using `+ transform.forward * 0.05f`?

Comment: Also not sure if it's right to use `Quaternion.identity` or rather `transform.rotation`